# How do I override the custom font in the Hugo book theme?

Tags: hugo

So I am building a site with the hugo-book theme. The docs [here](https://themes.gohugo.io/themes/hugo-book/) (under **Extra Customization**) say to create scss files under `./assets`, while the theme submodule itself stores its css defaults under `./theme/hugo-book/assets`.

Following this logic I created an scss file at `./assets/_fonts.scss`:

```css
/* merriweather-regular - latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Merriweather';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local(''),
       url('fonts/merriweather-v28-latin-regular.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Chrome 26+, Opera 23+, Firefox 39+ */
       url('fonts/merriweather-v28-latin-regular.woff') format('woff'); /* Chrome 6+, Firefox 3.6+, IE 9+, Safari 5.1+ */
}
/* merriweather-italic - latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Merriweather';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local(''),
       url('fonts/merriweather-v28-latin-italic.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Chrome 26+, Opera 23+, Firefox 39+ */
       url('fonts/merriweather-v28-latin-italic.woff') format('woff'); /* Chrome 6+, Firefox 3.6+, IE 9+, Safari 5.1+ */
}

body {
  font-family: 'Merriweather', sans-serif;
}
```

but hugo is still picking up the default roboto font from the theme directory. The fonts are stored under `./static/fonts` and the hugo compiler seems to be picking up the changes.

Should I instead be making changes to the hugo-theme submodule and not worrying about it? That doesn't seem right. Searching the internet shows references to a `custom_css` params entry in `config.toml` but it would be pointing to `./assets` - is this not the default?

Asking here before I ask the hugo-book author, in case I am missing something simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create an **assets** folder from the root of your theme. This **assets** folder should not be inside any other folder.
For the fonts, create a folder by the name of **static** and inside of that create another one by the name of **fonts** and put your web fonts inside of it.
For the fonts to work, paste the font stylesheet into **_custom.scss** partial and change the URL path there. After that these should work without any issues.
Note: the static folder shouldn't be inside another folder.

- assets

  _custom.scss
- static/fonts

  webfonts.woff

Comment: Thanks - worked like a charm. Sorry for the delay in response, I had to put this project away for a while... ;-)